# jquery how to reach the end of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a previous and next link that appends text to a div, however I have been trying to figure out how to append to the ul from the `treeObj`. I also cant seem to start the page off on the first ID. It starts blank.

```
  $("#next-bt").click(function() {
    $('.tracks').removeClass('selected');
    clickedID++;

    if (clickedID > lastIndex)
      clickedID = firstIndex;
    $('#' + (clickedID) + '_tracks').addClass('selected');
    document.getElementById('player-digital-title').innerHTML = treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].trackName;


  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5f4uzokf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger the **`Next button`** in document ready:

```
$("#next-bt").click();
```

And you can add a condition in your handler to cancel the event:

```
if(clickedID > lastIndex)
{
    clickedID--;
    $("#next-bt").css('cursor', 'default');
    $('#' + (clickedID) + '_tracks').addClass('selected');
    document.getElementById('player-digital-title').innerHTML = treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].trackName;
    return;
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/067r9ytp/2/).

Comment: Marios version worked better, you where first to answer, however when clicking the previous button once you reach the end it takes 3 clicks for the previous button to work. Not sure if its my browser or the code tho.

Comment: It was, changed it 1min later dude!! Whatever

Comment: Don't fret man, answer has been updated. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: I don't, just took 1min to change the link but you were already seeing the previous one. No problem and thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you already control the `clickedID` in the `next-btn` / `prev-btn` handlers, you can disable the links there, instead of just resetting it.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLf2c0hp/1/

Additionally, you don't need to mix pure JavaScript and jQuery, unless there is a reason I didn't see.

For instance, instead of

```
document.getElementById('player-digital-title').innerHTML = treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].trackName;
```

you could do

```
$('div#player-digital-title').html(treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].trackName);
```

Comment: Thanks Mario for your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you didn't append your `ul` element with its child `li` elements on to the page, and that's why it wasn't working. I changed that and a couple other small things too. Below is your updated code. I hope you find it okay :-)

Updated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var treeObj = {
    "root": [{
      "id": "1",
      "trackName": "Whippin Post"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "trackName": "Sweet Caroline"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "trackName": "Tears in Heaven"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "trackName": "Ain't She Sweet"
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "trackName": "Octopus' Garden"
    }, {
      "id": "6",
      "trackName": "Teen Spirit"
    }, {
      "id": "7",
      "trackName": "Knockin on Heaven's Door"
    }, {
      "id": "8",
      "trackName": "Whales"
    }]
  };

  var clickedID = 1;
  var count = treeObj.root.length;
  var firstIndex = 0,
    lastIndex = 0;
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
  $.each(treeObj.root, function(i, v) {
    $ul.append(
      $("<li></li>").append($("<a></a>")
        .attr({
          "class": "tracks",
          "id": v.id + '_tracks',
          "href": v.id,
          "data-file": v.trackFile
        })
        .html(v.trackName)
      )
    );
    var index = i;
    if (index == 0)
      firstIndex = v.id;
    if (index == count - 1)
      lastIndex = v.id;
  });


  //append ul 
  $("#player-digital-title").append($ul);


  $("#player-digital-title ul li:nth-child(1) a").addClass('selected');

  $("#prev-bt").addClass('disabled');

  $("#next-bt").click(function() {
    $('.tracks').removeClass('selected');

    $("#prev-bt").removeClass('disabled');

    if (clickedID < lastIndex) {
      clickedID++;

      if (clickedID == lastIndex) {
        $("#next-bt").addClass('disabled');
      }
    }

    $('#' + (clickedID) + '_tracks').addClass('selected');

  });

  $("#prev-bt").click(function() {
    $('.tracks').removeClass('selected');


    $("#next-bt").removeClass('disabled');


    if (clickedID > 1) {

      clickedID--;
      if (clickedID == 1) {

        $("#prev-bt").addClass('disabled');
      }
    }

    $('#' + (clickedID) + '_tracks').addClass('selected');

  });


});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: pink
}
#player-digital-title ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.disabled {
  color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src=""></audio>

<a id="next-bt" href="#">
  <div class="player-musicnav-ff-column3">
    <ul class="musicnav-ff">
      <li class="ff">NEXT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a>

<a id="prev-bt" href="#">
  <div class="player-musicnav-ff-column3">
    <ul class="musicnav-ff">
      <li class="ff">PREV</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="player-digital-title">
</div>
```